# Making global var from string in PHP?

Tags: php

For example^

```
  $locale = 'locale_array'.$locale;
  global $$locale -?
```

Comment: Globals *and* variable variables... you just managed to take bad idea to a completely new level ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
$GLOBALS['locale_array'.$locale]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use session variables also. dont know if you need.

```
session_start('SID'); // important: use in every file you need the session vars
$_SESSION['loc'] = 'locale_array'.$locale;
```